# known vector, known scalar, and unknown matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say we have a known vector $v$, a known scalar $a$, an unknown matrix $A$, and the following equation:

$v^TAv=a$

Just based on these information, can we say anything useful about $A$?

And what if we assume that $A$ is symmetric?

Comment: If you assume that $A$ is a symmetric rank-${\tt 1}$ matrix, then the unique solution is $$A = \frac{avv^T}{v^Tv}$$ To obtain a higher-rank matrix, you can add any symmetric matrix $B$ such that $Bv=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a big expert, but I can give you some hints to start.

Let's say $a \ne 0$ and for some B and some $b \ne 0$ we have:

$$v^TBv=b$$

Then we can slightly change each element of B by multiplying it to some scalar:

$$A = \lambda B $$

Such that

$$v^TAv=a$$

The actual value of $\lambda$ is depending on matrix and vector dimension.

There is a bijection between the set of possible matrices A and the set of equivalency classes of matrices $\lambda B$, you just need to get a proper $\lambda$ and corresponding matrix A out of each class.

In other words, for each dimension 1 subspace out of $n^2$ dimension space of all matrices (where n is dimension of vector v) you can take one (and only one) matrix A.

If $a = 0$ it can be more interesting since A must be an operator that makes vector orthogonal to itself.

So for both $a = 0$ and $a \ne 0$ try it for small n and maybe you find some pattern.